# Tezos in BigQuery: blockchain analytics on public data

Tags: query

There are growing number of crypto currencies currently translated into public access via BigQuery by means of Google Cloud. For example, see [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/bitcoin-in-bigquery-blockchain-analytics-on-public-data), [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/ethereum-bigquery-public-dataset-smart-contract-analytics), or [here](https://xrpcommunity.blog/an-exploration-in-the-xrp-ledger-with-bigquery/). Also this [article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/michaeldelcastillo/2019/02/04/navigating-bitcoin-ethereum-xrp-how-google-is-quietly-making-blockchains-searchable/?ss=crypto-blockchain#23c94ff84248) in Forbes about this trend.

In the articles above, we can clearly see the motivation that was behind that decision.

Can we, as a Tezos community, make the similar effort and translate the entire blockchain into open DB format? It may be GCP+BigQuery or AWS+Redshift, etc.

That effort may require a constant synchronization, but example in this direction is already exists. For instance, [this baker](https://www.tzdutch.com/quicksync/) is delivering the current DB state on regular basis. This service allow anybody to grab the recent DB snapshot and use it.

Now, we may need to consider making entire DB available for SQL queries and searchable publicly. Projects involved in block exploration may be better positioned here.

Just want to ask what is needed for it? Is it something that requires deep knowledge of Tezos proprietary DB?

My guess that sooner or later every meaningful blockchain will be explored through Google. Everybody may have a chance to say "Hey Google, show me the block 327239 in Tezos" or simply type SQL in BigQuery and Google will present something similar to https://tzscan.io/327239 but using BigQuery with applied visual analytics. Just dreaming. But who knows, maybe there are people who have been thinking about it as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to what Ezy said [here](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/590/323), Cryptonomic actually *does* have plan to export data to Big Query. We have in the past reached out to the developer outreach person at Google who started this project and will get to the task once we catch up to the quickly-evolving features of the Tezos platform.

Comment: Awesome, we all we be waiting for this moment then

Comment: Thanks Vishakh for the update sounds exciting!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me this is a very good question and afaik such an effort is actively taken by [Cryptonomic](https://cryptonomic.tech/) in that direction. They are in the process of releasing  a quite flexible query system called [Arronax](https://medium.com/the-cryptonomic-aperiodical/arronax-an-analysis-oriented-block-explorer-bd3b5d4f9fcb) that is powered by [Conseil/ConseilJS](https://medium.com/@CryptonomicTech/conseil-and-conseiljs-are-now-in-beta-99c00d30a808) .

Answer (score 0):

Tezos BigQuery dataset is available now :)

https://medium.com/tezoscommons/tezos-public-finance-dataset-integrated-into-google-bigquery-6050726d2b96